# Do you have to use cross-validation on simple models with a low number of features?

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

Say I have a logistic regression model and a dataset that's 100 samples and 10 features (i.e. # features is equal to 10% the # of samples; general rule of thumb for unregularized models).

Can I evaluate the model performance on the entire dataset here, instead of doing something like cross-validation?

Do I have to use cross-validation? Is there a pitfall in not doing so? Are there any papers that show that even though you follow the rule of thumb, you can overfit?

Comment: Never heard this rule of thumb personally. "Can I evaluate the model performance on the entire dataset here, instead of doing something like cross-validation?"—you need a held-out set to assess generalization error. If you're worried about losing too many training examples, you can do leave-one-out cross-validation.

Comment: How would you know that you weren't overfitting to your specific dataset if you didn't do CV?